# A Ditty for the Moderators

Tags: discussion

### MODERATOR (to the tune of "Operator" (with apologies to Jim Croce's Estate))

```
Moderator, well could you help clean up this post?
See, the question I'm asking is obfuscated
My code is kinda crazed, and my explanation is oddly phrased
I must be smart because my community is gated

Isn't that the reason why I code? Well, let's forget all that
And give me the code to make it work right
So I can finish and say that it's mine and go on to crow
I've overcome the challenge, I've learned to code it well
I only wish my code was written by myself
That I didn't need any help, but I do because my code really smells

Moderator, well could you help me fix this mess?
Well, I can't grok the example that you just posted
There's nothing in my brain, ever since I had it drained
I think about a career that I thought would be easy...
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we hate fun.

Comment: We need an [tag:always-new-years-in-iceland] tag

Comment: I wish I could offer a bounty on meta. And to a question.

Comment: This would be awesome when done by Eminem.

Comment: I was thinking Weird Al Jancovik.

Comment: Vote to reopen this on April 1.